# Using stat function to find information in subdirectory in c

Tags: c

I'm am new to programming and I have to recreate the ls -l command for a project in c and I'm actually nearly done, however I have an issue, I'm using the stat() function to get all the information I need (the perms, the nb of hard link, time...) and when I launch it without specifying a directory it works fine but but when I try to enter in a sub directory to get the information inside, it doesn't work.

I tried to do this, but like I said, it doesn't work if you try to enter in a sub directory:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "my.h"

int total(const char *dir)
{
    struct stat statfile;
    DIR *dh = opendir(dir);
    struct dirent *d = readdir(dh);
    int blk = 0;

    for (int o; d = readdir(dh);) {
        if (d->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;
        stat(d->d_name, &statfile);
        blk += statfile.st_blocks;
    }
    mini_printf("total %d\n", blk / 2);
}

int all_perm(DIR *dh, struct dirent *d)
{
    struct stat filestat;
    struct group *grp;
    struct passwd *pwd;

    stat(d->d_name, &filestat);
    mini_printf((S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
    mini_printf((filestat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x. " : "-. ");
    mini_printf("%d ", filestat.st_nlink);
    pwd = getpwuid(filestat.st_uid);
    mini_printf("%s ", pwd->pw_name);
    grp = getgrgid(filestat.st_gid);
    mini_printf("%s ", grp->gr_name);
}

int flag_l(const char *dir)
{
    DIR *dh = opendir(dir);
    struct stat filestat;
    struct dirent *d = readdir(dh);
    char ftime[100];

    total(dir);
    for (int o; d = readdir(dh);) {
        if (d->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;
        stat(d->d_name, &filestat);
        all_perm(dh, d);
        mini_printf("%d ", filestat.st_size);
        my_strncpy(ftime, 3 + ctime(&filestat.st_mtime), 13);
        mini_printf("%s %s\n", ftime, d->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dh);
}
```

when I launch it by doing `./my_ls -l` it give this:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x. 1 max max 8  Nov 14 20:06 include
drwxr-xr-x. 1 max max 4  Nov 15 12:04 lib
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 max max 330  Nov 15 08:24 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 max max 22848  Nov 15 19:57 my_ls
```

but when I try something like `./my_ls -l lib` it does:

```
total 0
----------. 1000 root adm 0  Jan  1 01:00 my
```

If I understand it does this because the stat try to search the "my" folder inside my main folder instead of the "lib" but I don't know how to make it go in it (btw I am not allowed to use the chdir command, I would already have done it if I could).
Thanks you if you

Comment: Checking the return value of `stat()` and other functions to see if it worked or not, and if not, printing out a helpful diagnostic message with `perror()`, will go a long way towards improving your code and making it easier to track down problems.

Comment: When you want to stat the files inside a folder given on the command line, you're reading a directory but you're not prepending the directory name to the name returned in the `readdir` call. So, you're effectively stat'ing the file as if it's in the current working directory.